# iPhone XCode compiling ADHOC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I inherited some source code and am now trying to adhoc compile it.
However, I'm seeing this error message

CodeSign error: The entitlements file '/Users/teepusink/Documents/i_think_the_original_guys_path/Entitlements.plist' is missing

Where can I change that path? I do see that there exist an Entitlements.plist file and I've changed the Code Signing identity to mine.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

Got the same problem and had to fix it manually in the XCode project file. XCode did not accept my changes via "Get Info".

- make a backup first!
- open your .xcodeproj file by right clicking the file in Finder.app and selecting "Show Package Contents"
- open project.pbxproj
- search for "/Users/teepusink/Documents/i_think_the_original_guys_path/Entitlements.plist"
- delete the lines with CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = "/Users/teepusink/Documents/i_think_the_original_guys_path/Entitlements.plist";

After that I was able to re-add the Entitlements.plist file and it showed up there with the correct path and the build process ran without errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by right clicking on your Target under Targets in Groups & Files, hit the 'Get Info' option. Select `Adhoc` from the Configuration dropdown at the top left, then change `Code Signing Entitlements` to the path of the Entitlements.plist file located on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to fix a path is to just delete the file reference in your project, make sure the file is where you want it (move, copy, check out from the repository), and then (re)add the file/plist to your project.